# identify this ant queen

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

can anyone help me identify this ant queen, if it's an ant queen? I only assume it is because I caught another with wings which looks exactly the same. Thanks in advance..
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

There is only one segment between the thorax and the abdomen and the first segment of the abdomen is not elongated, which indicates this is a Formicinae.

Because the head width is similar to the thorax width from top view, this likely corresponds to a social parasite ant from the genus *Lasius*.

See ref below:

> Seifert, Bernhard. Die Ameisen Mittel-und Nordeuropas. Lutra Verlag-u.
>   Vertriebsges., 2007.